# bind to another app service in standby mode

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In android 6 there are a new feature named Standby app mode.
According to documentation - app in standby mode not allowed to do background work and network communications.

Let's consider I have two applications, one client and second app with service.

Client requests for data to service, and service goes for data to network. Then service receive data from network and sends to client. (via bindService and AIDL)

I just wondering, if second service app went in app standby mode, and client request to it for data , does service will be able to make network request or no?

p.s. My suggestion was no, not allowed, but I've tested it in on device with android 6, and all worked fine. But I what to be sure about this behavior.

Comment: `I've tested it in on device with android 6, and all worked fine` - then the answer is yes, is it not?

Comment: I am not sure I've tested it correctly, I've used 'adb set-inactive' and 'dumpsys battery unplug' commands

Comment: Is the service a foreground service? If yes, it can't go into standby, if not it can be idle and network access disabled

Comment: no, service is not foreground